# Texture Repeat/Wrapping/Loop/Stitch in Blender Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, image, looping

I'm trying to wrap/loop/repeat a small texture in the Real Time Compositor in a similar way you do it in the Shading Editor. But it doesn't look like there is a way to do this. Does anyone have any tips for me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one tedious way (sorry, i am a compositing noob, hopefully there are more elegant ways to do it) would be this:

[image]

So you can use the scale + transform node to make your image smaller and via alpha over you can add it to your background.

Comment: Haha, ah dang. This is what i was afraid of. I'll just go ahead and do it -_- Thanks for confirming. appreciate it!